# Integrating telegram bot with google cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

I have an issue, I have my telegram bot (created with Node and Telegraf library) and I want this to be hosted on google cloud functions, so whenever I call a command cloud function get triggered.
I have this:

```
 //imports
bot.start((ctx) => {somecode});

bot.command('Instagram', (ctx) => { somecode };

bot.command('Collaborazione', (ctx) => { somecode });

bot.telegram.setWebhook('myHTTPsTrigger');

bot.launch();

exports.myBot = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    functions.logger.info('Hello logs!', { structuredData: true });
    return await bot.handleUpdate(request.body, response).then((rv) => {
        // if it's not a request from the telegram, rv will be undefined, but we should respond with 200
        return !rv && response.sendStatus(200);
    });
});
```

When I run it locally it works, when I do the deploy for the first 10 minutes it work (the timeout is setted by default to 1 minute), but the next day it doesn't work...

Can somebody help me?

**SOLVED**

I turned the async function into a normal function and I removed the return

```
exports.myBot = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 bot.handleUpdate(request.body, response)
})
```

Comment: Instead of editing the question Can you post your answer as a solution? So,that it will be useful for others who are facing the same issue

```